# There is some way to disabled set of inputs in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have some inputs in md-card.
there is a way to do like:

```
 <md-card-content [disabled]="phone._id>
```

Instead each one?
tanks.

Comment: Can you please restate your question? I don't understand it. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can create a `<fieldset>` which, unlike other elements like `<form>`, accepts `[disabled]` property.

All these fields that require to be disabled together have to be place inside it, just like in the following example:

```
<fieldset [disabled]=[true]>
  <input type="text" ...>
  <input ...>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is not fully supported in IE, only some fields actually become disabled: https://caniuse.com/#feat=fieldset-disabled

Comment: What if you have buttons into the disabled fieldset and you have to enable it? I mean, all of the input, textearea, select, including buttons going to be disabled with the attr disabled in the parent fieldset.