# How do I create a disabled form having child components?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-changedetection

For the life of me, it seems like I should be able to create a disabled FormArray. I'm trying to build a view-only parent form (FormArray) with 1-n subarrays (also FormArray). I pass the subarrays down to the child components to initialize their controls (FormControl).

I've tried calling `disable()` on the parent form with different options and at different hooks of the life cycle, it throws this exception:

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'.
>   Current value: 'false'.

Here's are a couple examples of some of what I've tried:

- in `ngOnInit`, both create and disable form -> does not disable, throws exception
- in `ngOnInit` create form, in `ngAfterViewInit` disable form -> DOES disable but throws exception

An older version of forms accepted an options object, and (sadly) this no longer works but would have looked like: `new FormArray({ value: myControlsArray, disabled: true })`.

I created a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VOYs1D) to model the component hierachy and form.

Does anyone know how to initialize a disabled form?

---

Edit (answer): I overlooked an important piece of information and clue to the solution. In my use case, I take a saved form value and initialize a new read-only form. Instead of passing the saved form value to the child component, I instead should have created the parent form and its sub-forms and controls.

Comment: you can't create disabled form, first you should create it then disable.

Comment: @RomanC I hope my question made it clear that's the current method I'm using. Please note the change detection exception it's causing. Ideally there would be a way to initialize the form in a disabled state, but realistically I need help figuring out where/how to call the `disable()` method so it doesn't trip up change detection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the edit, I'm using a saved form value to initialize a new read-only form. Rather than pass the value to the child component to initialize its controls, I solved this in large part by constructing the controls at the same time as the parent form and sub-forms. Doing so I could disable the parent form in `ngOnInit` without tripping change detection and still pass the sub-forms down to the child components. Here's an excerpt of what it looked like and the [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/VOYs1D):

app.component.ts:

```
public questions: Array<string[]> = MULTIPLE_RADIOS;

public responses: Array<string[]> = MULTIPLE_RESPONSES;

constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this._fb.array([]);
    for (let response of this.responses) {
      const questionForm = this._fb.array([]);
      for (let responseControl of response) {
        questionForm.push(this._fb.control(responseControl));
      }
      this.form.push(questionForm);
    }
    this.form.disable({ emitEvent: false });
  }
```

app-radio.component.ts:

```
@Input()
public form: FormArray;

@Input()
public radios: string[];

constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnChanges() {
  // same component used to create a live form
  // in this case, its parent (app-question.component) gives
  // it an empty form, and the child adds the control it needs
  if (this.form.length === 0) {
    this.form.push(this._fb.control(''));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a disabled `form`. But you can create a disable set of `input` (`fieldset`), which turns out to be the same if your group is as big as the form.

```
<fieldset [disabled]=[true]>
  <input type="text" ...>
  <input ...>
</fieldset>
```

See [There is some way to disabled set of inputs in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115252/there-is-some-way-to-disabled-set-of-inputs-in-angular-2/)

Comment: Although clever and a good reminder on HTML basics, this didn't solve my problem. Angular 2 didn't bind the `disabled` attribute on the `<fieldset>` to my form so while functionally disabled, they didn't apply visual styling for the disabled state.